# Link grow font on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a list of links and when hovering them, I want the font grow smoothly.

Currently the font grows instant, even when using `transition`.

```css
#menuHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menuItem {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menuLink {
  transition-property: font-size;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
}

.menuLink:hover {
  transition-property: font-size;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #97d700;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menuItem" id="menuHeader">Title</li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a class="link menuLink" href="/">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a class="link menuLink" href="/">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a class="link menuLink" href="/">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is an example page

https://www.roidna.com/services/

The links attached in the blocks grow their size when hovering over them.

Comment: Declare the `transition` property to the *natural* element state so that it applies to both the natural and hover states. Then declare **only one** `transition-property` rule, the cascade order will only apply the last rule and negate any preceding statement of the same type. Consider using the shorthand property; `transition` to apply the transition effects to any property changes of the element (e.g: `color` and `font-size`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some overriding going on. You need to declare them on one line:

```
transition: color 0.5s, font-size 0.5s;
```

```css
#menuHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menuItem {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menuLink {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, font-size 0.5s;
  transition: color 0.5s, font-size 0.5s;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
}

.menuLink:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #97d700;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menuItem" id="menuHeader">Title</li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a class="link menuLink" href="/">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a class="link menuLink" href="/">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a class="link menuLink" href="/">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.menuLink {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;

    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s, font-size 0.3s;
       -moz-transition: color 0.3s, font-size 0.3s;
         -o-transition: color 0.3s, font-size 0.3s;
            transition: color 0.3s, font-size 0.3s;
}

.menuLink:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #97d700;
}
```

Maybe this could help you

Comment: Please also explain the changes and why the code of the topic starter did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Transition should be applied only to .menuLink class. We don't apply it to hover. Just change the code to the following code.

```
.menuLink {
  transition: font-size 300ms ease-in-out;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
}

.menuLink:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #97d700;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might like the CSS syntax:

```
transform: scale(1.1);
```

This might work better as it doesn't affect the other links